# Vertical and horizontal text align in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How simply change align text in flex box in this case?

I am trying to align text to `flex-start`, but something is going wrong and I can't understand what. I think that main style doesn't make a change or in this case I need to use something else, not an `align-items`. I need to align all text (`md-card-title`, `md-card-subtitle`, `md-card-content`) to the `flex-start`.

**`goods.component.css`**:

```css
md-card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 500px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

md-card-title {
  font-size: 32px;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

md-card-subtitle {
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

md-card-content {
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

md-grid-tile {
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

h1 {
  color: #673ab7;
  text-align:center;
  margin: 1em 0 0.5em 0;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 58px;
  line-height: 54px;
  text-shadow: 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

a {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #673ab7;
}

.price-content{
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #00bd0d;
  float: left;
  height: 22px;
  line-height: 22px;
  padding: 0px 9px 0px 9px;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

**`goods.component.html`**:

```html
<h1>All goods</h1>
<md-card>
<md-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="3:1">
    <md-grid-tile  [colspan]="1" [rowspan]="3">
        <img md-card-image src='./assets/image/001.jpeg' alt='picture'>
    </md-grid-tile>
    <md-grid-tile  [colspan]="2" [rowspan]="1">
        <md-card-title><a [routerLink]='["/goods"]'>Audi A8</a></md-card-title>
    </md-grid-tile>
    <md-grid-tile  [colspan]="2" [rowspan]="1">
        <md-card-subtitle>Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description</md-card-subtitle>
    </md-grid-tile>
    <md-grid-tile  [colspan]="2" [rowspan]="1">
        <md-card-content class="price-content">50000 $</md-card-content>
    </md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
</md-card>
```

Comment: Please, explain what you got and what you expect.

Comment: i got all text in block on center. want to change it to the flex-start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the `justify-content`/`align-items` property is used/set on the flex container, element with those properties also need `dispay: flex` or else they will have no effect.

And in this case it is these 4 rules

```
md-card-title
md-card-subtitle
md-card-content
md-grid-tile
```

*Some of the properties used doesn't need to be set as it is their defaults (see notes in CSS)*

Stack snippet

```css
md-card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;      
  /*align-items: stretch;                  not needed, default  */
  width: 500px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

md-card-title {
  font-size: 32px;
  display: flex;                       /*  added  */
  align-items: flex-start;
  /*justify-content: flex-start;           not needed, default  */
}

md-card-subtitle {
  display: flex;                       /*  added  */
  align-items: flex-start;
  /*justify-content: flex-start;           not needed, default  */
}

md-card-content {
  display: flex;                       /*  added  */
  align-items: flex-start;
  /*justify-content: flex-start;           not needed, default  */
}

md-grid-tile {
  display: flex;                       /*  added  */
  align-items: flex-start;
  /*justify-content: flex-start;           not needed, default  */
}

h1 {
  color: #673ab7;
  text-align:center;
  margin: 1em 0 0.5em 0;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 58px;
  line-height: 54px;
  text-shadow: 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

a {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #673ab7;
}

.price-content{
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #00bd0d;
  float: left;
  height: 22px;
  line-height: 22px;
  padding: 0px 9px 0px 9px;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<h1>All goods</h1>
<md-card>
  <md-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="3:1">
    <md-grid-tile [colspan]="1" [rowspan]="3">
      <img md-card-image src='./assets/image/001.jpeg' alt='picture'>
    </md-grid-tile>
    <md-grid-tile [colspan]="2" [rowspan]="1">
      <md-card-title><a [routerLink]='["/goods"]'>Audi A8</a></md-card-title>
    </md-grid-tile>
    <md-grid-tile [colspan]="2" [rowspan]="1">
      <md-card-subtitle>Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description Description</md-card-subtitle>
    </md-grid-tile>
    <md-grid-tile [colspan]="2" [rowspan]="1">
      <md-card-content class="price-content">50000 $</md-card-content>
    </md-grid-tile>
  </md-grid-list>
</md-card>
```

Comment: add but nothing change. See what it works, but i cant understand why it not working.I think some style cant apply. Mayby some default style .mat-grid-tile .mat-figure {} - this style i see on page and if i change it, it work. But i cant understand were i found location of this file(

Answer (score 0):

The Flexbox works only on the direct child elements. You try to align elements outside the "Flexbox-Area". The `md-grid-list` need also `display: flex;`

Comment: add too but result is the same. Text in "block" align on center